# How to blur a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [**Vague.js**](https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/vague.js) to blur a `div` but I can't seem to get it working.

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).load(function() {
    var vague = $('.zero').Vague({
        intensity: 3,
        forceSVGUrl: false
    });

    vague.blur();
});
```

I've tried `$(document).ready(...)` first, that didn't work, so I switched to `.load(..)`

HTML:

```
<div class="block zero">
    <img src="images/rb.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.zero {
    background: url(../images/11.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  // Put your code here
});

Comment: Use document.ready instead, see [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BMCwC).

Comment: I tried $(document).ready() already, forgot to put that.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: "I can't seem to get it working." What does mean? No effect at all? Any error?

Comment: @Archer Yeah, two. One is irrelevant (missing css where I store my fonts), the second is: **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'Vague'**

Comment: @A. No effect, and 1 error displayed above.

Comment: This error means you are not including Vague plugin correctly or too late. Check network tab for 404 error

Comment: @A. Noted, I moved it around, and it works now. Thanks all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `$(document).load(` to [`$(document).ready(`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var vague = $('.zero').Vague({
        intensity: 3,
        forceSVGUrl: false
    });    
    vague.blur();
});
```

or use

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

or use Shorthand for `$( document ).ready()`

```
$(function(){
```

Comment: I did that at first, it didn't work, which is why I tried `.load(..)`

Comment: are you included `Vague.js` , it should be after jquery library

Comment: Ah, I moved it around, and it's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

instead of:

```
$(document).load(function() {
```

Comment: I used `.ready(...)` at first, it didn't work. I just tried your first suggestion, that didn't work either.

Comment: Yes, someone mentioned to move the order of the js around, and it's solved. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the permissions on the Vague.js are set to 755. Assuming a LAMP stack of course.

Comment: I'm doing this locally, so I don't think permissions are a problem.

Comment: I would check either way, just to rule it out. I had a local setup as well, and the settings on external .js where all messed up.

Comment: .js is also local in this case, but thanks for letting me know. I'll keep it in mind.